# Double integration of this equation

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Can I have some help as to how this integrand be integrated?
$$\int_{0}^{1}t^{n+1}\left ( u''v-v''u \right )dt+\int_{0}^{1}\left ( n+1 \right )t^{n}\left ( u'v-uv' \right )dt$$

Comment: notice that $(u''v - v''u) dt = d(u'v -uv')$ and then use integration by parts.

Comment: I get $$(u'v-uv')$$ as the end answer

Answer (score 0):

If we define
$$f(t) = u'v - uv'$$
then 
$$f'(t) = u''v + u'v' - (u'v' + uv'')$$
$$ = u''v - uv''$$
This allows your integral to be expressed as
$$I = \int_{0}^{1}t^{n+1}f'(t)dt + \int_{0}^{1}(n+1)t^nf(t)dt$$
Now we use integration by parts on the left hand integral to get
$$\int_{0}^{1}t^{n+1}f'(t)dt = [t^{n+1}f(t)]_{0}^{1} - \int_{0}^{1}(n+1)t^nf(t)dt$$
and so substituting this back into the original expression for the integral we have
$$I = [t^{n+1}f(t)]_{0}^{1} - \int_{0}^{1}(n+1)t^nf(t)dt + \int_{0}^{1}(n+1)t^nf(t)dt$$
which after cancellation is just
$$I = [t^{n+1}f(t)]_{0}^{1}$$
$$ = f(1)$$
$$ = u'(1)v(1) - u(1)v'(1)$$